# Non-empty intersection.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A_1,A_2,...,A_{2019}$ be sets s.t. $|A_i|$=45 for each $i=\overline{1,2019}$ and $|A_i\cap A_j|=1$ for every $i\neq j$. Is it true that $$\Big|\bigcap _{i=1}^{2019} A_i\Big|=1?$$

What I thought of doing is proving by induction by i, the base is obvious. However I'm stuck on the next step.

Comment: Induction can't really work here, because roughly speaking you're using that $\sqrt{2019} \leq 45$ to then apply pigeonhole principle.

Answer (score 5):

If $B:=A_{2019} = \{1,2,...,45\}$ then, by pigeonhole priciple, some $x\in B$ is in at least $45$ sets among sets $A_1,A_2,...A_{2018}$. So $x$ is in at least $46$ sets, say $B,A_1,..,A_{45}$.

Now suppose some set $A_i = \{a_1,...,a_{45}\}$ (for some $i\geq 46$ and $i\ne 2019$) does not contain $x$.

Then some element $a_i$ must be in two sets from the list: $B,A_1,..,A_{45}$. But then these two share $x$ and $a_i$. A contradiction.