# Combinatorics problem with students choosing elective courses. (Prove by assuming the opposite).

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are ***2009*** different elective courses in the university. Each one of the courses has exactly ***45*** students in it. Every ***2*** courses has exactly ***1*** student in common. Prove that there is a student enrolled in all courses.

I think it should be proven by assuming the opposite.
Maybe there is a connection that ***2009***/***45*** is less than ***45*** but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3960498/non-empty-intersection?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

We will see the courses as a sets of students, where $x \in Y$ means that $x$ is enrolled in course $Y$ and $x = Y \cap Y'$ means that $x$ is the common student of $Y$ and $Y'$ (we omit curly braces around $x$).

We can prove the following lemma.

#### Lemma: There is a student enrolled in all courses, or each student is enrolled in at most 45 courses.

**Proof:** For a contradiction, let there be a student $a$ who is enrolled to more than $45$ courses, but not to all courses. The courses of $a$ will be denoted by $C_1, \dots C_k$, where $k > 45$. Let $C'$ be a course to which $a$ is not enrolled.

We have $\forall i \not = j < k: C_i \cap C_j = a$. Therefore, the student which a $C_i$ shares with $C'$ must be different for each $i$ (otherwise, the $|C_i \cap C_{i'}| > 1$). That is impossible by the pigeonhole principle ($C'$ have only $45$ students, while the range of $i$ is greater), which concludes the proof of the lemma.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Thus, we may assume that each student is enrolled in at most $45$ courses, otherwise, we have the desired student.

Now, we can count the pairs $(\text{x}, \text{Y})$, such that the student $x$ is enrolled to course $Y$. Each course has exactly $45$ students, which gives $45 × 2009 = 90405$ pairs. However, each student can take up to $45$ courses by our assumption, which gives as most $45 × 45 = 2045$ pairs, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, the assumption regarding the maximal number of courses for a student cannot hold, which implies (by the lemma) that there is a student who took all courses.

$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$